# How to improve this query using array or json constructor?

Tags: postgresql

how are you?

I am wondering how to improve this query to return something better to work with. Let me show the tables, the current query and my idea first:

### Tables

users

[image]

nfts

here owner_id is a fk to users.id

[image]

users_nfts (here I save all the creators of the nft, one nft could have more than one creator. This is to calculate royalties later)

[image]

### Current query and explanation

To be able to code a "buy" nft process (in nodejs) I want to retrieve some data about the nft to buy:

- Its price
- Its current owner
- The creators (to calculate the royalties and update their balances)

```sql
SELECT nfts.id, price, owner_id, owner.balance as owner_balance, creators.user_id, users.balance
FROM nfts
INNER JOIN users_nfts as creators
ON nfts.id = creators.nft_id
INNER JOIN users
ON creators.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN users as owner
ON nfts.owner_id = owner.id
WHERE nfts.id = ${nft_id}
```

The query works but it's horrible because it retrieves me repeated data (this is what I want to solve). The red square means the repeated data.

[image]

### What I would like to achieve

I would like to make a query so all the data about the NFT comes in one row. To do that, I need to retrieve the user_id and balance inside an array of tuples or in a json.
The result in my backend could be something like (any ideas here are welcome):

```js
{
    "id": "ea850c65-818e-40bd-bb06-af69eaeda4a6", // nft id
    "price": 42,
    "owner_id": "1134e9e0-02ae-4567-9adf-220ead36a6ef",
    "owner_balance": 100,
    "creators": [
        {
            "user_id": "1134e9e0-02ae-4567-9adf-220ead36a6ef",
            "balance": 100,
        },
        {
            "user_id": "2134e9e0-02ae-4567-9adf-220ead36a6ea",
            "balance": 35,
        },
    ],
},
```

Thanks in advance for any tips :)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I want with this query, using `json_agg` and `json_build_object`

```sql
SELECT nfts.id, price, owner_id, owner.balance as owner_balance, json_agg(json_build_object('user_id', creators.user_id, 'balance', users.balance)) as creators
FROM nfts
INNER JOIN users_nfts as creators
ON nfts.id = creators.nft_id
INNER JOIN users
ON creators.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN users as owner
ON nfts.owner_id = owner.id
WHERE nfts.id = ${nft_id}
GROUP BY nfts.id, owner.id;
```

The query produces the following output:

```js
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "d87716ec-4005-4ccb-9970-6769adec3aa1",
            "price": 42,
            "owner_id": "7dd619dd-b997-4351-9541-4d8989c58667",
            "owner_balance": 58,
            "creators": [
                {
                    "user_id": "1134e9e0-02ae-4567-9adf-220ead36a6ef",
                    "balance": 137.8
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "492851bb-dead-4c9d-b9f6-271dcf07a8bb",
                    "balance": 104.2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope someone else can find this useful.